# How to change amount order from Amazon Pay after authorized?

Tags: php, amazon-pay

I have the specified case with Amazon Pay.

After authorized success, I want to change the original amount of order.

Example: I create an order with amount is 2000$ to Amazon Pay. I want to change amount from 2000$ to 3000$.

I can't find any APIs in Amazon Pay to change amount after authorized.

How can I change amount of order after authorized Or Amazon APIs not support ?

Comment: @TobiasF.: I just want to update the payment has just authorized and not capture. If you know please help me

Comment: I don't know anything about amazon pay but I'm pretty sure that they don't allow you to change the price after the customer has agreed to pay a certain price. Just imagine how many scams such a loophole would create.

Comment: @THess: I'm not sure, but I read some information from officially page Amazon https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-onetime/handling-post-purchase-modifications.html#sample-scenario--payment-amount-increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From officially Amazon Pay: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-onetime/handling-post-purchase-modifications.html#sample-scenario--payment-amount-increase

I found out the way to change original amount. 
I will re-call Authorize with amount is not exceed 15% total amount or 75$.
The link API for authorized: 
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-api/authorize.html